# Is there a better way to wait for Kubernetes job completion?

Tags: kubernetes, jobs

I currently use the following script to wait for the job completion

`ACTIVE=$(kubectl get jobs my-job -o jsonpath='{.status.active}')
until [ -z $ACTIVE ]; do ACTIVE=$(kubectl get jobs my-job -o jsonpath='{.status.active}') ; sleep 30 ; done`

The problem is the job can either fail or be successful as it is a test job.

Is there a better way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. As I pointed out in [kubectl tip of the day: wait like a boss](https://hackernoon.com/kubectl-tip-of-the-day-wait-like-a-boss-40a818c423ac), you can use the [kubectl wait](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#wait) command.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to wait for multiple conditions? or negative condition?

Comment: AFAIK it is not.